# NetBeans 9.0 Mac OSX Cannot find HTML/JS Project Templates

Tags: javascript, project, netbeans-9

I just installed Netbeans 9.0 using the [Mac installer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8gdC7BBtbs)

However, when I click on new projects, I don's see HTML5/JavaScript Projects? Node.JS projects? I guess it is the only version available for Mac.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Netbeans 10. HTML/JS project templates are restored.